# node-postgres: Performance drops drastically as we keep sending queries

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

We recently switched from mysql to postgresql, and we are using node-posgres to send queries. Everything runs fine for a few minutes, and then queries start slowing down until our service is no longer usable.

Here is an example of output:

```
fetchRows: Pool has 56 clients, 1 idle clients, 0 queued waiting requests.
Query SELECT * FROM  mytable executed in **232775 ms**
```

At the beginning of the day, that query takes 2ms, 3 minutes later it takes 11513ms and it keeps getting worse.

It is not a problem with the db itself, I can run this query with psql and this table is empty (12 columns, no rows). The db doesn't show any active query, so apparently they are stuck somewhere upstream.

Has anyone seen this problem before? We are sending a lot of queries, maybe we are flooding the system?

We are using "pg" version 8.11.1, on node 16. pg  pool is configured with 100 max clients, and idleTimeoutMillis = 30000.  Most of our queries use the callback version of pool.query(), only a few use pool.connect() to handle transactions. The db and node server are on the same host.

Any pointer is appreciated. We are looking into potential network issues as well.
Thanks

Comment: Look at the Postgres logs and see what is hitting the database. One theory `commit` is not being issued and everything is being done in one transaction which is holding open resources. Also see [Transactions](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions).

Comment: Use `top` to see if the bottleneck is CPU, and if so which process it is in.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. Postgres logs are not showing anything, but we think we didn't set-up the logs properly. I will follow your leads and keep you posted.

Comment: The postgres db is not receiving the requests, and both activity and locks look ok. CPU loos ok as well. Requests are stuck in the node-postgres layer, maybe trying to get a pool client.

Comment: The problem was a bunch of logstash clients piling up in the node event loop. We found it thanks to https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running. Not related to posgresql and node-postgres. Queries were slowing down as a side effect.